# jQuery.trim() is not working

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON string which is coming in Ajax success function, If I alert the data it is showing me the below string but If I want to trim and get the value of any particular key, It is showing no result.

```
{"ProviderID":"28","Status":"Provider has added [sdfd] successfully!","ContactEmail":"sdf","ConnectorName":"TestName","Name":"sdfd","Contact":"sdf","ConnectorID":"1"}
```

This is the result I want to achive, basically the value of key but it is not giving the any result.

```
" + $.trim(data.ProviderID) + "
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/pfLhyq33/. What does the full string look like? I presume this is a smaller part of a larger string, as you've got obviously broken quote syntax. Also note that `$.trim()` is of little benefit over the standard `trim()` method

Comment: unclear with what you are asking......if you want the `ProviderID`, then `var data = JSON.parse(responseString)` and `data.ProviderID` to get it. Why `$.trim()`?

Comment: Thanks Rory and j4rey89 , I find the issue. The issue with the JSON object and JSON string conversion. Now I am using dataType : json which is sorted out my problem but really thankful for both of you. Cheers